# Converter data frame pandas para array

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho um dado que, de .txt, converti para um Dataframe (DF) com pandas.
Para as várias atividades que realizei é bem conveniente que seja um DF.

Há apenas uma coluna com valores, além do índice.

[image: DF]

Agora, gostaria de converter o DF em um array.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Algo como `lista = df['nome_coluna'].tolist()`?

Comment: Klel, veja se [isso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187778/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-numpy-array-preserving-index) ajuda

Comment: AlexCiuffa, me apareceu o erro: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'

Comment: Tuxpilgrim, é que meu dado é apenas uma coluna, precisaria que, ao converter para o array, se tornasse apenas uma linha.

Answer (score 3):

Klel, nesse caso voce pode utilizar a função:

'*pandas.DataFrame.values*'

Segue o exemplo de utilização:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'idade':    [ 3,  29],
                   'peso': [94, 170]})
vetor = df.values
```

Para passar todo o DF para um array.

Ou então diretamente atribuir uma única coluna a um array.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'idade':    [ 3,  29],
                   'peso': [94, 170]})
vetor = df['idade'].values
```

Na última linha basta colocar coluna desejada.

Segue o [Link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas.DataFrame.values) para a documentação.

**Exemplo com 1 coluna**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'idade':[ 3,29,13,15,16,14,12]})
vetor = df.values
```

Comment: Olá Clayton, o problema é que meu dado é apenas uma coluna, precisaria que, ao converter para o array, se tornasse apenas uma linha.

Comment: A questão de ser uma só coluna não tem problema Klel. Adicionei um exemplo contendo somente uma coluna

Answer (score 0):

Um outro método que você pode usar é o **to_numpy()**

Esse método converte um DataFrame em um array Numpy.

```
df.to_numpy()

array([[nan, 0.2, nan],
       [nan, nan, 0.5],
       [nan, 0.2, 0.5],
       [0.1, 0.2, nan],
       [0.1, 0.2, 0.5],
       [0.1, nan, 0.5],
       [0.1, nan, nan]])
```